# Problems with getting same height as width for view programmatically on API level > 24 android

Tags: android

For an app I an ImageButton which I want to have the same height as width, done programmatically. I found a solution online which let's me set the height as soon as the width is known with:

```
    class SizeListenerClass implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener{
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout(){
        View v = (View)findViewById(R.id.imageButton0);
        int height = v.getWidth();
        imageButton0.getLayoutParams().height = height;

    }
}
```

And calling it like this:

```
imageButton0.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new SizeListenerClass());
```

In the onCreate() method of my activity.
Now for API level < 24 this works perfectly, starting from API level > 24 however this doesn't work anymore.

The xml of the ImageButton is the following:

```
<ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

I can't find a suitable solution to this problem, any ideas?

Comment: make a custom `ImageButton` class and override its `onMeasure` method, no need for any other `onGlobalLayout` etc

Comment: Going to try that out right now , thanks for the answer

Comment: If you don't call setLayoutParams after change some param then your are doing nothing.

Comment: I tried it out and you're right. But isn't it weird that this perfectly works on API < 24?

Comment: Also not always changing width or height in LayoutParams will change the view size, it depends on what type of Layout the view is contained, on RelativeLayout probably will change in others may not ... Also other defined rules  like layout_right_of ...can affect.